# Quick falsy-truthy way of checking IE or not?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I read an article about *[Test for Internet Explorer in JavaScript](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/test-for-ie-in-javascript/)* which states that a quick test is :

```
var isMSIE = /*@cc_on!@*/0;

if (isMSIE) {
  // do IE-specific things
} else {
  // do non IE-specific things
}
```

But one of the [**comments**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/test-for-ie-in-javascript/#li-comment-86904) showed another way :  ( and I have to say  , it works)

```
if (-[1,]) {
// do non IE-specific things
} else {
// do IE-specific things
}
```

And so I ask  :

What is so special with `-[1,]` that IE doesn't recognize it while others do ?

p.s.

found another quick falsy-truthy trick

```
IE='\v'=='v'
```

Comment: You should avoid browser sniffing whenever possible and instead strongly prefer feature detection of what you need to do.

Comment: Maybe you should focus the question title more around the `-[1,]` part, that seems quite interesting

Comment: @AndrewMarshall There are some scenarious where you have to deal with special hacks. for example : there is a label which says "uploadfile" and the label should open a fileuploader(hidden) as if you pressed it. now  - a Lbael with FOr attribute will do the job. but it behaves differently in chrome vs Ie. and so , i need to detect.  there are other alternative  , i know , but still my question remains.

Comment: `[1,].toString()` in IE *prior* to recent versions was `"1,"` which when prefixed with arithmetic `-` would output falsey `NaN` whereas other browsers would return `[1,].toString() == 1` for a truthy `-1`.  Its a horrid sniffing technique, avoid it entirely.

Comment: @AlexK. please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Regardless of your needs, you still have the issue that your title does not match your actual question...

Comment: @musefan I guess you havent seen the edit :-)

Comment: I hadn't seen it no... although I am still not entirely convinced (but will let it pass). However, I appreciate how difficult it would be to come up with an appropriate title. I certainly don't have any suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[1,].toString()` in IE prior to recent versions was `1,` which when prefixed with arithmetic `-` would output falsey `NaN` whereas other browsers would return `[1,].toString() === 1` for a truthy `-1`.

Its a horrid sniffing technique, avoid it entirely and as other have commented detect support for specific features.